# Is there a Windows utility that can be used to receive mails via POP?

Tags: email, user-interface, utility, blat

Is there a utility (like [Blat](http://www.blat.net/)) that can be used to receive mail, perhaps via POP?
I need something that's

- A Windows Executable (no DLLs)
- Simple to use
- Doesn't need to be installed
  I'm trying to make a simple email interface for my program. Any ideas would be appreciated.

While on the subject, is there a good free email provider that doesn't demand secure logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeode.com/popclient/index.html